# ROOT - Uninstall app in background without prompt dialog

Tags: android, root, uninstallation

Hi guys i have a rooted phone based on Android 7.1.1 and i want uninstall apps without prompt the dialog (back or uninstall confirmation). My app has root privilege and it is also a system app. I have tried to use shell command via "pm uninstall" command but it doesn't works:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su pm uninstall " + packageName);
```

I got "Magisk/E: Unknown id: pm". I tried many other combination, with shell prefix etc but nothing. Root works very well and in manifest file i put the perm "DELETE_PACKAGES". The same command works if i execute it via PC.

How i can do to uninstall an app without dialog ?

Comment: `su` does not take these arguments. Try `su -c '<whatever>'`

Comment: Oh my god i'm stupid. Thanks man. Answer my question so i can give you the best answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su pm uninstall " + packageName);` try running `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c 'pm uninstall " + packageName + "'");`

In your code you have forgotten to add `-c`, so `pm uninstall [...]` is regarded as arguments of the `su` command.

Comment: as i promised here my "best answer". Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You could try this using DataOutputStream:

```
        try
        {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes("pm uninstall " + packageName + "\n");
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();

            p.waitFor();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```